# I need my script to accept input from a file rather than read-host

Tags: powershell, file, copy, file-get-contents

I have a ps script which will ask for a number, then search for that number in a location with 1000s of files, copy those file names having those number and then output it to a file. That number is also saved in a txt file in a different location, from which I manually copy and insert into this script. Is it possible to make the script read from the 2nd line onwards of the file containing the number, then search for that number within files, like it is doing now?
This is the code I am using:-

```
$Path = "D:\Projects\MSMQ Journal Messages\PurchaseManagementPO"

$Text = Read-Host -Prompt "PO Number"

$PathArray = @()

$Results = "D:\Chayan\POmiss\miss.txt"


# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".xml".

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.xml" |

Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |

ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) 
{
$PathArray += $_.FullName

$PathArray += $_.FullName
}
}
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"

$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File "D:\Chayan\POmiss\miss.txt" -Append
```

### That PO Number comes from a file, which is generated through a different script, and gets saved like below:-
ponumMaster

```
 908859

 280973
```

I manually put these number in the read-host to do the search and save file name. Is there a way powershell can copy these numbers from this file and do the task?

Comment: use get-content -path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#we clear this variable so it can be run multiple times in the same session

clear-variable final -ErrorAction Ignore

#grab txt file content and split into an array

[array]$txt=(get-content "D:\Chayan\POmiss\miss.txt") -split " "

#take out the blanks and assign to new variable called final (we clear this above so it can be run multiple times in the same session)

foreach($line in $txt){
    if($line.replace(" ","")){
        [array]$final+=$line
    }
}

#run script, calling the variable $text in place of the numbers

foreach($text in $final){
    
    (your normal script here)
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `-skip` to move past the first line

The example below would skip the first line and give the results after that

```
get-content C:\_lab\test.txt | select -skip 1
```

This example would skip the first line and only give the results from the second line

```
get-content C:\_lab\test.txt | select -first 1 -skip 1
```

For your script, you should just need to do the following:

```
$Text = get-content C:\_lab\test.txt | select -skip 1
```